# Backup Debian Jessie 64 webserver on VPS and restore on Debian Jessie 64 on VPS

Tags: linux, backup, 64-bit, tar, debian-jessie

I rent a VPS in a datacenter running an apache2 webserver, nodejs, webmin, phpMyadmin and many more software installed and configured on a Debian Jessie 64.

The OS was initially installed with the defaults concerning the disk partitioning so no LVM and things.

Now i'm looking into a backup and recovery plan that i need to restore the complete setup in let's say 10 minutes or so.

I came accross this appealing solution that smply states that you make a nice Tar beginning from the root off the system to backup and if needed it can be untarred at the root of a new system with only the OS (debian Jessie 64) and you have you'r fresh completely identical sytem back online and running.

Only thing left to do is change the ip in DNS and we are happy.

I'm trying the solution described here: http://www.aboutdebian.com/tar-backup.htm

I'm pretty sure it can't be just that easy and i have the feeling that certain files and dirs should be excluded from the backup. eg. network interfaces? Seems to me when you copy that from one to the other that conflicts arise since the new VPS has another ip from it's Host and things like that.

I also can understand that the dir /proc is the dir where all data is concerning the running processes on a machine and should absolutely not be backed up to restore?

Is there a simple answer on this matter on how to go about using this Tar thing? 
What should i exclude and what should be configured on the target machine when the tar is untarred?

**Edit**
Simply tarring it and untarring it doesn't do the trick.
Untarring it to a seperate folder i can see eg. the apache2 dir. When unpacked at the root it isn't visible what makes the instructions complete BS.

Let's try further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tiny miserable fstab file in the /etc folder was the one preventing me from getting it done. Excluding it did the trick. Costed me 10 hours of trying to exclude this and that and this and that! :)

So the backup is this:

```
tar -zcvpf /tars/$archive_file --directory=/ --exclude='etc/fstab' -- exclude='boot' --exclude='dev' --exclude='var/www/uploads' --exclude='tars'  --exclude='proc' --exclude='sys' --exclude='tmp' --exclude='run' --exclude='mnt' --exclude='media' --exclude='lost+found' .
```

And then at / on the new system with a fresh basic install of Debian Jessie 64:

```
tar -zxvpf transonly-Sunday.gz
```

Reboot and Voila! :-)

Answer (score 0):

i think this should do it, just modify it for your needs.

backup.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Backupscript mit TAR
# Definieren der Konstanten
###########################
HOSTNAME="YOUR-SERVER-NAME-HERE"
# Backupname
BACKUPNAME="How your backup will be called"
# Emailempfaenger
EMAIL_TO="your-mail@com"
# Emailsender
EMAIL_FROM="Your Name <your-mail@asdf.com>"
# Backup Verzeichnis
BACKUP_DIR="/root/scripts/backup"
# zu sicherende Files
LIST=$BACKUP_DIR"/backuplist"
# exkludierte Files
EXLIST=$BACKUP_DIR"/excludelist"
# Name des Backup-Device
#OUTDEV="/dev/st0"
OUTDEV="BACKUP-PATH/backup.`date +%A`.tar.gz"
# Log-Datei
LOGFILE=$BACKUP_DIR"/backup.`date +%A`.log"
# Copy Log
LOGCOPY=$BACKUP_DIR"/copy.log"
# Mail Subject Log
SUBJECT_LOG=$BACKUP_DIR"/subject.log"
# Mount Log
MOUNT_LOG=$BACKUP_DIR"/mount.log"
# tar Kommando zum sichern
# TAR_SICH="tar cvf"
TAR_SICH="tar cvzf"
# tar Kommando zum lesen
# TAR_READ="tar tvf"
TAR_READ="tar tvzf"
# tar Kommando zum zurueckspulen
# TAR_REWIND="mt -f /dev/st0 rewind"
# erwartete Filenamen
FILE_EXP=$BACKUP_DIR"/file_expected"
# gesicherte Filenamen
FILE_BCK=$BACKUP_DIR"/savedfiles"
# gelesene Dateien
FILE_READ=$BACKUP_DIR"/file_read"
# Fehler bei erwartete Filenamen
ERR_EXP=$BACKUP_DIR"/tar_find_error"
# Fehler bei gesicherte Filenamen
ERR_BCK=$BACKUP_DIR"/tar_write_error"
# Fehler bei Band zurueckspulen
ERR_REWIND=$BACKUP_DIR"/tar_rewind_error"
# Fehler bei gelesene Dateien
ERR_READ=$BACKUP_DIR"/tar_read_error"

# Sicherungsprotokolldateien auf NULL setzen
rm $LOGFILE $FILE_EXP $FILE_BCK $FILE_READ $ERR_EXP $ERR_BCK $ERR_REWIND $ERR_READ $SUBJECT_LOG $LOGCOPY $MOUNT_LOG 2> /dev/null
echo "Beginne Sicherung"
echo `date` > $LOGFILE
echo

makebackup() {
    # Ins Root Verzeichnis wechseln
    cd /


    # Eintrag in die LOG 
    echo -n "Start TAR Datensicherung: " >> $LOGFILE
    date >> $LOGFILE
    echo >> $LOGFILE

    # Backuplist in Logfile schreiben
    echo >> $LOGFILE
    echo "Backuplist: " >> $LOGFILE
    cat $LIST >> $LOGFILE
    echo >> $LOGFILE

    # Sichern mit dem TAR Kommando
    echo "Beginne Sicherung ..." >> $LOGFILE
    $TAR_SICH $OUTDEV -T $LIST -X $EXLIST > $FILE_BCK 2> $ERR_BCK
    if [ -s $ERR_BCK ]; then
        cat $ERR_BCK >> $LOGFILE
    fi
    echo "Beende Sicherung ..." >> $LOGFILE
    echo >> $LOGFILE

    # Rueckgabewert von TAR Sicherung speichern
    RC=$?

    # Anzahl gesicherte Dateien speichern
    ANZ_SICH_FILES=`wc $FILE_BCK | awk '{print $1}'`
    echo "Anzahl gesicherte Dateien: " $ANZ_SICH_FILES >> $LOGFILE

    # Dateiverzeichnis des Bandes mit dem TAR Kommando lesen
    $TAR_READ $OUTDEV > $FILE_READ 2> $ERR_READ
    if [ -s $ERR_READ ]; then
        cat $ERR_READ >> $LOGFILE
    fi

    # Anzahl gesicherte Dateien speichern
    ANZ_READ_FILES=`wc $FILE_READ | awk '{print $1}'`
    echo "Anzahl gelesene Dateien  : " $ANZ_READ_FILES >> $LOGFILE
    echo >> $LOGFILE

    du -hs $OUTDEV >> $LOGFILE

    # Wenn die Anzahl erwarteten Dateien ungleich der gelesenen ist
    if [ $ANZ_READ_FILES -ne $ANZ_SICH_FILES ]; then
        echo "FEHLER bei Datensicherung " > $SUBJECT_LOG
        cat $SUBJECT_LOG >> $LOGFILE
        echo -n "Ende Datensicherung: " >> $LOGFILE
        date >> $LOGFILE
    else
        echo "Datensicherung erfolgreich abgeschlossen " > $SUBJECT_LOG
        cat $SUBJECT_LOG >> $LOGFILE
        echo -n "Ende Datensicherung: " >> $LOGFILE
        date >> $LOGFILE
    fi

    if [ $ANZ_READ_FILES != $ANZ_SICH_FILES ]; then
        echo "FEHLER bei Datensicherung " > $SUBJECT_LOG
    fi

    echo >> $LOGFILE

    # Mail Benachrichtigung
    mail $EMAIL_TO -r "`echo $EMAIL_FROM`" -s "`echo "Backup"` - `echo $HOSTNAME` - `echo $BACKUPNAME` - `cat $SUBJECT_LOG`" < $LOGFILE

}



makebackup

#EOF
```

backuplist (must be in the same folder as the script)

```
/bin
/boot
/etc
/home
/lib
/lib64
/opt
/root
/sbin
/usr
/var
```

excludelist (also in the same folder)

```
/var/lib
/var/spool
/var/run
/root/scripts/backup
```

Comment: Creating the Tar with your script an d untarring it at the root of the new machine result in: ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/xxxxxxxxx does not exist. Dropping to a shell
initramfs:_      It should also be clear that i have no physical access to the servers.

Comment: trying it again with /boot exluded

Comment: Strange, /dev should not be backuped, and so on it should not copy anything there, normally you should have all your config files backed up.

Comment: So maybe it would be better to extract the tar in a subdir (for example /root/restore) and then copy the important files back to their place.

Comment: Do you have root access to your server?

Comment: Yes, i have root access since it is an unmanaged VPS i rent. I'm now playing with apt-clone and backing up the folders like apache2, letsencrypt, www, mysql. Since i have no physical access tot the server this seems like an option that should work well. With apt-clone all of the applications get installed on a fresh install of the new Jessie and the important folders moved (mv)  from backup. Not finished yet and working on it.

Comment: also not with satisfying results. now again with: tar -zcvpf /tars/$archive_file --directory=/ --exclude= --exclude='dev' --exclude='tars' --exclude='proc' --exclude='sys' --exclude='tmp' --exclude='run' --exclude='mnt' --exclude='media' --exclude='lost+found' . and unpack it at / of a fresh netinstall denian Jessie 64. Which will probably result in the same error concerning dev. Last time i trie this one!

Comment: Unpacked it in seperate folder and moving them one by one to find out that overwritng the /etc folder is resulting in a read only filesystem.

Comment: This tiny miserable fstab file in the /etc folder was the one preventing me from getting it done. Excluding it did the trick. Costed me 10 hours of trying to exclude this and that and this and that! :)